# Why isn't my inline assembly in C++ working?

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

Strangest error output:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int arg, char **LOC[])
{
asm
(
"mov eax, 0CF;"
"pusha;"
);
return 0;
}
```

It complains, and here is the error from GCC:

> t.s: Assembler messages:
>
> t.s:31: Error: too many memory references for `mov'

Comment: [Good to read](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html)

Answer (score 9):

You get this error because your assembly is malformatted. Register accesses are done like `%eax`, `$` is used for immediate operands. Furthermore, GCC, by default (see DanielKO's comment), uses the AT&T syntax, which has the destination on the right and the source on the left. Is this what you are looking for?

```
mov $0xcf, %eax
```

Also, your `pusha` is unbalanced, ie you don't clean up the stack correctly before you return from your function. It would be nice to know what your overall goal is, because right now it seems like you copied and pasted only an incomplete fraction of the source.

Comment: While at it, it's worth mentioning the `-masm=intel` GCC flag.