# Inline assembly code won't compile for nothing ... is this a compiler issue?

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly

I tried this with GCC:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
asm("mov $0x7, %al");
}
```

And this is what outputs:

> Exited: ExitFailure 7

So I tried this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
    asm("mov $0xcf, %eax";);
    }
```

And get this error:

> error: expected `)' before ';' token.

I tried [this guy's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778272/why-isnt-my-inline-assembly-in-c-working), but it doesn't work. [This tutorial says otherwise.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15971/Using-Inline-Assembly-in-C-C)

I did exactly as shown in the tutorial, as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
asm("movl $10, %eax");
}
```

And get this error:

> Exited: ExitFailure 10

What does an "ExitFailure" mean exactly, and why are they corresponding to the values in the operands? Basically, what is going on here? Is it wrong on my part or the compilations?

PS: This is an error log; my program doesn't compile successfully.

Comment: WHen it says exit, that means that program was compiled and executed.

Comment: _ExitFailure_ is what sounds problematic.

Comment: it says exit failure because it returns something !=0

Comment: But the linker is not releasing the binary, so there is a real issue compiling.

Comment: Your first snippet was, accidentally, effective at setting the main() function return value.  Duly reported by whatever tool you used to run your program.  The better way to set the main() return value is to use the *return* statement.  Covered well in any introductory book about the C language.

Answer (score 4):

Your program is compiling and running just fine - you just happen to be putting the values `7` and `10` into `eax`, which causes the return value of your function to be `7` or `10`, respectively - that behaviour depends on your ABI.

Comment: I do not believe that "ExitFailure" signifies something "_just fine_". I am also not specifying any output to the console or such, so the result I am talking about is an **error**, not output on a console program.

Comment: Why not?  It's just the exit status of the program, which was explicitly specified by your code.

Comment: Read what I posted above ... this is an _error output_ on the compiler log; the program never executes.

Comment: @LastLifeHump; to clarify experiment with `asm("movl $0, %eax");` and compare with `return 10;` and `return 0;`

Comment: I should see no log telling me "ExitFailure", I expect to see a successful compilation log. The program does not compile successfully.

Comment: @mythagel Wow, your suggestion actually worked! Thanks, friend! What was the problem, I still wonder?

Comment: @LastLifeHump There is no problem. As explained by Carl you are returning a non-zero exit status. Exactly the same as `return 10`. Nothing to do with the asm.

Comment: I think you misunderstand still. Your program has both compiled and executed successfully. Your platform will interpret the returned value in some platform dependant manner. In this case whatever tools you are using seem to interpret a non-zero exit status as failure.

Comment: @mythagel  The linker did not place the binary executable file in any directory. How is that successful compilation? Only an object file exists in the project folder.

Answer (score 2):

Your main function is missing a return value, add `return 0;` or whatever you wish to return.

Comment: The C++ rules dictate that falling off the end of `main()` (and only `main`) is the same as executing `return 0;`.

Comment: I did, and it makes absolutely no difference with or without it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiled fine and executed fine on gcc 4.8.1.. It even says `Process terminated with status 0 (0 minutes, 1 seconds)`. I compiled it with codeblocks and Mingw-builds 4.8.1.

You can even try it online here gcc 4.8.1: http://ideone.com/dUcDc1

or gcc 4.3.2

http://ideone.com/tNFWZH

Either way, it still works.. Returns 0 as well.

[image]

Now as for a possible error for you.. The reason the other answers say that you are trying to return 10 is because in assembly when you move a value onto eax and call ret, it returns that value.

Thus you're essentially telling the compiler that main is going to return `10` or `7` or `')'` according to your code.. That is why they are suggesting you try moving 0 into the eax register.

If you're compiling with g++ x64, then you'll need to move it into rax iirc.. Not sure about that though but I do know for eax this is true.

Now as to why it works for me and others.. It may be platform dependent or your compiler may be buggy.. Some platforms actually interpret the return code to mean something.

For example, returning anything other than 0 on some platforms.. the os might lookup the return code and cleanup in a certain way depending on what the return code even means.

Comment: Well, on my compiler (no IDE) there's still ExitFailure, and the linker does not place the binary in the specified directory.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ZRBTxKo.png  Maybe check your commands? What os are you running on? What version of gcc? What commands did you input?

Comment: Windows 7, latest GCC, everything else optimum. No input commands.